# How to round median value

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have problem, I cannot the fix bug with scalar-valued function.
I have next function:

```
(@list varchar(max))
returns float
as
begin

    declare @Median float
    select @Median = (
    convert(float,(SELECT MAX(value) FROM
    (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT value from split(@list,',') order by value) BottomHalf))
    +
    convert(float,(SELECT MIN(value) FROM
    (SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT value from split(@list,',') order by value DESC) TopHalf))
    ) / 2
    option (maxrecursion 0)

    return  (ROUND (@Median ,2))

end
```

In the response, I get for example: 1.155.
when I add return  `(ROUND (1.155 ,2))`
I get 1.15 but I need 1.16. I try add `ROUND(CAST ( 1.155 AS float ),2)` but it not helped me

Comment: To be clear this `select ROUND (1.155,2)` gives you `1.15` ? check again

Comment: yes, in the result I have 1.15 but need 1.166

Comment: Can you try this ? `select ROUND(1.155,2,0)`

Comment: sorry, when I try select ROUND (1.155,2) in query I get 1.16

Comment: On a separate note, if your split returns `value` as a `varchar`/`nvarchar`, your `MIN` and `MAX` may not be the same as numeric `MIN` and `MAX`. Also why do need to do `SELECT TOP 50 PERCENT value from split(@list,',') order by value DESC` twice for both `min` and `max`. why not do a simple SELECT (MIN(value) + MAX(value))/2 FROM split(@list,',') assuming the split returns value as numeric or use a `CAST/CONVERT` to convert the value to a numeric and then use aggregate functions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presumably, your return value is more like 1.154999999.  This will round down.  If you need to still get 1.16, then try declaring `@median` to have three decimal places:

```
declare @median decimal(18, 3)
```

I question whether this is what you really need.  But [here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7) is a SQL Fiddle.